# Browser cache leveraging via .htaccess in a Laravel app not working

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I'm trying to set the `Cache-Control` header for the images in my Laravel 5.5 app. I'm using the **.htaccess** file (placed in the `myapp/public` directory):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # rewrite directives...
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|svg)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Unfortunately, the `Cache-Control` header is not being set for the specified static resources, so I must be doing it wrong.

**Is it the .htaccess syntax I'm getting wrong, something Laravel-specific, or something else entirely?**

**Update:**
I forgot to mention the server I'm working with - Nginx, which is an important clue, [as it turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47751006/2890610).

Comment: check whether the modules are enabled in your server

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

```
# BEGIN Expires-Headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 weeks"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END Expires-Headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control-Headers
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
  <filesmatch "(gif|ico|jpeg|jpe|jpg|svg|png|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
# END Cache-Control-Headers
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am very badly informed.

I'm using **Nginx** (not Apache) server for my application, and apparently, Nginx doesn't work with the .htaccess file. Instead, it needs [custom configuration](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-browser-caching-with-nginx-s-header-module-on-centos-7).